# Hector mapping not creating map

Tags: navigation, laser, hector, network, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a LIDAR connected to an AR drone, with drivers running on the drone to read the laser data, and send it to my ros master computer using netcat. I have written a ros driver in python that listens to the network and reads the incoming laser data, creates a LaserScan message, populates all the fields and then publishes this to /scan.

I can see /scan in rostopic list, and can see populated messages in rostopic echo /scan. However when I run my launch file which runs hector_mapping, no map is created. I know the launch file works as I have tested it with the LIDAR connected directly to the master computer using the official drivers and it builds a map fine.

So I think there must be a problem when I populate the LaserScan message and publish it. I have included one of my populated messages below, can anyone see anything wrong with it or suggest something else which I can try? I have noticed the seq fields in the header are always 0 but have read I shouldn't set that myself and leave ros to deal with it.

```
Node: /laserlistener
Time: 21:56:49.521363019 (2016-04-05)
Severity: Info
Published Topics: /rosout, /scan

header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1459889809
    nsecs: 520699977
  frame_id: laser
angle_min: 3.14159265359
angle_max: -3.14159265359
angle_increment: 0.0174532925199
time_increment: 0.000515921866295
scan_time: 0.18521595
range_min: 0.15
range_max: 6
ranges: [0.0, 0.0, 1274.25,  ... ] omitted as lots of numbers, all look correct though
intensities: [ ... ] ditto
```

The angle_min and angle_max fields are meant to be like that (at least that is what the official driver spits out) I have also tried 0 to 2*pi

Launch file:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map2odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 100" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom2base_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_frame 100" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_frame2base_footprint" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_frame base_footprint 100" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_footprint2base_stabalized" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_footprint base_stabalized 100" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_stabalized2base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_stabalized base_link 100" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link2laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map2scanmatcher_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map scanmatcher_frame 100" />

<include file="$(find hector_slam_launch)/launch/tutorial.launch"/>

<param name="use_sim_time" value="false" />

<param name="hector_mapping/pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/>

<!-- Map size / start point -->
<param name="hector_mapping/map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
<param name="hector_mapping/map_size" value="2048"/>
<param name="hector_mapping/map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="hector_mapping/map_start_y" value="0.5" />
<param name="hector_mapping/map_multi_res_levels" value="5" />

<!-- Map update parameters -->
<param name="hector_mapping/update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="hector_mapping/update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
<param name="hector_mapping/map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.01"/>
<param name="hector_mapping/map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
<param name="hector_mapping/laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
<param name="hector_mapping/laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />
<param name="hector_mapping/laser_min_dist" value="0.4" />
<param name="hector_mapping/laser_max_dist" value="4.0" />

<param name="hector_trajectory_server/trajectory_update_rate" value="4" />
<param name="hector_trajectory_server/trajectory_publish_rate" value="4" />
```

Publishing node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

import roslib;
roslib.load_manifest('laserdrone');

import rospy;
import math;
import tf;
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan;

import socket;
import numpy as np;
import time;
import sys;

if **name** == '**main**':
rospy.init_node('laserlistener');

```
pub = rospy.Publisher("scan", LaserScan, queue_size=10);

rate = rospy.Rate(10);

host = '';
port = 44444;

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
sock.bind((host, port));
sock.settimeout(15);
sock.setblocking(1);
sock.listen(0);

try:
    print "Waiting for incoming data for 15 seconds"
    request, addr = sock.accept();
except:
    print "timed out"
    sys.exit(0);


print "Connected"
angs = [];
dists = [];
Qs = [];
results = []

oldang = -1;

lastTime = rospy.Time.now();

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    
    data = request.recv(10);
    while (data.find("\n")==-1):
        data += request.recv(1);
    
    #print data;
        
    try:
        line = data.split(","); #90.0, 1000.45, 12
        if len(line) != 3:
            continue;
        
        ang = float(line[0].strip());
        dist = float(line[1].strip());
        Q = float(line[2].strip());
        
        angs.append(ang);
        dists.append(dist);
        Qs.append(Q);
        
        if(ang < oldang):
            #publish here
            print "Publishing now";
            
            thisTime = rospy.Time.now();
            duration = (thisTime - lastTime).to_sec();
            lastTime = thisTime;
            
            print thisTime.secs, thisTime.nsecs, duration;
            
            # print thisTime, lastTime, thisTime-lastTime, thisTime.to_sec();
            
            lasermsg = LaserScan();
            
            lasermsg.header.stamp = lastTime;
            lasermsg.header.frame_id = "laser";
            
            lasermsg.scan_time = duration;
            lasermsg.time_increment = duration / 359;
            
            lasermsg.angle_min = math.pi;
            lasermsg.angle_max = -math.pi;
            lasermsg.angle_increment = math.pi / 180;
            
            lasermsg.range_min = 0.15;
            lasermsg.range_max = 6;
            
            lasermsg.ranges = dists;
            lasermsg.intensities = Qs;
            
            rospy.loginfo(lasermsg);
            pub.publish(lasermsg);
            
            angs = [];
            dists = [];
            Qs = [];
            
        oldang = ang;
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise   
    except:
        print "err, data:",data, ", ", sys.exc_info()[0];
    
rate.sleep();
```

Many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231107/hector-mapping-not-creating-map/) by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2016-04-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on 2016-04-05**:
Could you also upload your launch file? I guess it may cause by launch file connect.

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-04-06**:
Knew I'd forgotten something! Added launch file and he publishing node

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-04-06**:
Can you visualize the scan via rviz? Also, I saw you set the max range to be 6m but i also saw the laser scan data `1274.25`. Are you sure all the laser scans have correct distances. In Hector slam, the scan will be filtered by the `laser_max_dist` set in launch file (4m in your case)

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-04-07**:
I cannot visualise with rviz, it counts up the messages coming in so is definitely receiving them. Very true, when I run it with the actual drivers all the numbers are much smaller. I will check the code and post back

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-04-07**:
Yes that was it! The numbers were in millimetres instead of meters. Thanks for the pointer

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-04-07**:
Don't know how to mark this as answered either as these are only comments to the original question

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-04-07**:
That s great. You can write your own answer of how you fixed it in the answer session.

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-04-08**:
I've added it, but says I need >10 points to accept my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out the drivers I was using on the AR drone were giving out millimetres instead of the meters that LaserScan is expecting. After dividing the output by 1000, I get a map and pose as expected. Thank you to DavidN for pointing it out

---

Originally posted by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) with karma: 55 on 2016-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-04-08**:
You now have 11 points and can answer your own question :P

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-04-09**:
Ah nice, thanks